# Return to Cmder prompt after npm start

Tags: node.js, cmder

I am using Cmder on Windows to start a ReactJS tutorial. When I run

```
npm start
```

Everything seems to work pretty well, it says "Compiled successfully," and a new browser tab opens with my web app. Node.exe is open in the cmder console, and I can't type anything. How do I close Node.exe and get back to the prompt? Is there a nice way to do it, or do I have to close the whole window?

Answer (score 1):

To cancel any currently running process, you can press `Ctrl + C` and it will ask you if you are sure you want to `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`

At this point, you can type `y`  and then press `Enter` and you will be back to the prompt.